Laravel 11 - This password does not use the Bcrypt algorithm
Error during Auth::attempt($credentials) . Followed https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#authenticating-users
I've created simple seeder:
$hashedPassword = Hash::make('password');
        User::factory()->create([
            'name' => 'Admin User',
            'login' => 'admin',
            'password' => $hashedPassword,
            'role' => 'Admin',
        ]);

Phpmyadmin
I am trying to log in user with
 public function loginUser(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('login', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }

        return back()->withErrors(['login' => 'Invalid login or password']); // Redirect back with error message
    }

I am getting error even if password in DB is hashed. Did I miss something ?

Can you please share exact error that you are getting??

Whole error

Do dd($credential) to verify the data that is sent to Auth::attempt().

data are correct, login and unhashed password

maybe it's because both hashing algorithms are different. Try setting HASH_VERIFY as false in the hashing.php file and check if everything works, if it works then the problem is there are two different hashing algorithms have been used.

I think your bug is because the password is encrypted by default and you re-encrypt it with a specific encryption.
Use this code and it will probably work
User::factory()->create([
    'name' => 'Admin User',
    'login' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'password',
    'role' => 'Admin',
]);


I changed to 'password' => 'password', in create method and also changed User class to class User extends Authenticatable
Now it's working as it should.

In my case the problem solved when i change my hashed password in database from starting '$2a$' to '$2y$'
eg: $2a$12$POGG9oYZvS/8ijd8PiA3Q.bxTMMv4Ca77nIdZ6VFOEJOQGtM4ltUC
to this,
$2y$12$POGG9oYZvS/8ijd8PiA3Q.bxTMMv4Ca77nIdZ6VFOEJOQGtM4ltUC

open your terminal run this command
php artisan config:publish hashing

Then open file
config/hashing.php

Set bcrypt verify to false
'bcrypt' => [
    'rounds' => 12,
    'verify' => false,
],


No! You should not disable security features!

What exactly does this disable?

@PiTheNumber I think it's a bug, according this Issue and This is how to solve it at least for now

@Alex it's to prevent hash algorithm manipulation attack, you can read more about this issue here
